# Python: can get json from a website with error msg 'Missing X-LVS-HSToken'

Tags: python, html, json, python-requests, token

```
def downloadWebPageJSON(url):
headers = {'Accept':  'application/json'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

When navigating a on specific website, I can see that part of the data (information) is not available in the html code. I found out that they are loaded from a JSON file instead.

I managed to get the address to reach the JSON, and would like to download the content. However when I requests.get the JSON I get an error message 'Missing X-LVS-HSToken'

First of all, even thought the website has an authentification to get into our account, the webpage I'm talking about can be accessible by anyone without account (ie: I loaded the page with private browser mode without login - and it still displays the content information I want)

So my question is do you have any idea what can be the cause and how to solve.
I guess it is all about having a auth code or something to get token.

```
No idea if it can help:
Header when I want to reach the html page:
{'Date': 'Thu, 24 Mar 2022 16:05:03 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'X-Powered-By': 'Express', 'Cache-Control': 'public, max-age=300', 'ETag': 'W/"43725-aI4pOr4UXwc5yoFiJHmtU4ruXZU"', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Content-Security-Policy': "frame-ancestors 'self' https://*.fdj.fr;", 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'X-XSS-Protection': '1; mode=block', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload;', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'Keep-alive', 'Keep-Alive': 'timeout=15, max=100'}status of the html >>> 200

header when I want to reach the JSON:
{'Date': 'Thu, 24 Mar 2022 16:05:03 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'X-Request-Id': 'e435f855-a5c9-4e23-af47-a7d017988752', 'ETag': 'W/"23-xWDQjX9a9skCFe+6I7MkqH0I+1c"', 'Set-Cookie': 'abp-pselw=abpwfr11004_1443; Path=/lvs-api', 'Content-Length': '35', 'Connection': 'Keep-alive', 'Keep-Alive': 'timeout=15, max=100'}status >>> 401
```

On the browser, I can't access to json directly - I get the same error message.
However if I load the html page first it seems that the browser get the token and then when I refresh the Json page then it load all the content.

But I could not do the same within my python script. I tried to requests get the html first then the Json but sill the error message remain.

Comment: Are you trying to access Etherscan or some blockchain site? Can you share the URLs that are giving the issue?

Comment: Problem solved :

When I request the html, I found out that inside the html code there is a part of json which contains HSToken.So I pass this HSToken into the headers when I request the Json and it works :)